# Safe to cache Expresso Store "exp:store:product" tag?

Tags: expresso-store

I am wanting to cache the output of the exp:store:product tag. This seems like a safe thing to do, with one possible exception. The generated form contains a hidden `_params` field, the value of which changes with every request. **Is it safe to cache this? Or is there something I'm not considering?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll notice that the hidden `_params` field does change with each request (due to how the encryption works), but it **is safe to cache**. It's basically just an encrypted version of the Product tag parameters, so as long as your Product tag parameters don't change with each request (e.g. it contains segment variables or other dynamic variables), it's safe to cache this.

The only problem you might run into is the `XID` field which is generated fresh on each request and is **not safe to cache**. However, you can get around this by either disabling secure forms, or it's possible that CE Cache and other caching plugins take into account the XID and update it after loading the cached fragment. You would need to check with the plugin author or documentation about this. At least with the XID it will be really obvious if it is broken (every form submission after the first would break, so you would notice immediately).

Comment: @MattFordham Did you got that solved or not? I have same exact "problem" with CE Cache.

Answer (score 2):

The hidden `_params` field is there to encrypt any [parameters](https://exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#product_tag_parameters) you include in your Products tag. For example, if you specify some required fields then the parameters just act as an extra layer of security here to stop someone potentially modifying the form to remove the requirements upon submission. It should be safe to cache these as they generally wont change once configured but if you make any changes to the tag parameters then just be sure to clear the cache first.

Answer (score 1):

If the hidden _params value changes with every request, surely it's not safe to cache. I don't know this definitively but it's what I would conclude.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too...

Comment: If you're considering using CE Cache, you may be able to use the {exp:ce_cache:escape} tag around the Store tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Store Product Form most likely you would need to escape the form for security reasons. Otherwise you will get a security issue with the form submission.

We will work on removing this in v3.